# Suggested Reading? Applications of the Krull-Schmidt Theorem for Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, ring-theory, lie-groups

I'm currently reading about the Krull-Schmidt Theorem for groups, and am wondering how I can learn more about its role in group theory. Thus far I have read the proof sketch given in Hungerford's algebra and done the exercises in the chapter pertaining to K-S, but there are only two of them, and I am looking to see what types of broader insights this theorem might offer about groups.

The KS theorem for groups seems incredibly powerful, but whenever I attempt to research it I find the KS theorem for rings and modules or Krull-Schmidt Categories.

I did end up reading about formulating Krull-Schmidt using projective covers, but lack an intuition for what this would look like in the category of groups with the bi-chain condition.

Does anyone have suggestions for papers or other references?

Comment: If i remember correctly the earliest time I read about it was during the development of composition series

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937285/nonexample-to-krull-schmidt-groups?rq=1); some people call it [Remak-Krull-Schmidt](http://people.brandeis.edu/~igusa/Math101b/RKS.pdf), but this should be the same. It is more important for modules, see wikipedia.

Comment: thank you both very much